# How does roles_mask work in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, roles

Set up my app following the tutorial on railscasts [189 Embedded Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association). So like in the tutorial I added

```
t.Integer :roles_mask
```

to my users table and the following to my model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

    ROLES = %w[admin moderator author]

    def roles= (roles)
        self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2** ROLES.index(r) }.sum
    end

    def roles
        ROLES.reject { |r| ((roles_mask || 0) & 2** ROLES.index(r)).zero? }
    end

    def role_symbols
        roles.map(& :to_sym )
    end
end
```

Everything works well adding and removing role using forms. But how can I achieve this from the console? And how exactly does it work, how rails is able to identify a string role from an integer value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahaa! My favorite logic! It is magic of `bits`. In machine language, everything is presented in zeroes and ones (0-1). Now coming back to roles

```
ROLES = %w[admin moderator author]
```

For each role specified in the model, it assigns one bit.

```
admin moderator author 
1     1         1
```

For a user instance, if you give him that role, that bit becomes `1` else `0`.

```
u = User.new
u.roles = [:admin]
u.admin? #=> true
u.roles_mask #=> 1
admin moderator author 
1     0         0
# Read it in reverse as 0 0 1 which in binary means 1. That's why roles_mask is 1
u.roles << :author
u.roles_mask #=> 5
admin moderator author 
1     0         1
# Read it as 1 0 1 which in binary means 5. That's why roles_mask is 5
```

So, it's just bit magic and nothing else which maintains roles allocation :) Read more about binary to decimal conversion [here](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/binary-to-decimal.htm)

If you see the [README](https://github.com/martinrehfeld/role_model) of role_model gem, it mentions:

> # declare the valid roles -- do not change the order if you add more
>     # roles later, always append them at the end!

This IS the very season it is mentioned. If you change the order, a user with persisted value of `1` wouldn't know about what you did!